# Wrapping MQTT data in SSL certificate while sending it to MQTT broker

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I am using MQTT python client running on RPI. I am not a guy from Web related field, but i need to implement SSL security while i send some data from my python client to a open source MQTT broker.

I had find out [certain package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html) in python for wrapping up SSL security while opening a socket. I am kind of new in python. So i want to understand it how it work and what we need to do if we want to implement SSL security.[This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work/20833#20833?newreg=876bebb591fc4ef78a2ebc0edac52645) explain much about SSl and how does it happen. But what if i need to implement it with python and how will i install a SSL certificate locally on my RPI (i want some short of open source SSL certificate as i am doing this as local project as of now.)

I used below python code to open a SSL socket and then connect to www.google.com over 443 port.

```
import socket
import ssl

s_ = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s = ssl.wrap_socket(s_, ca_certs='/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/cacert.pem',cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)
s.connect(('www.google.com', 443))
s.write("""GET / HTTP/1.1\r
Host: www.google.com\r\n\r\n""")
d=s.read()
print(d)
s.close()
```

and i get this output on my console

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=PkW8U8SsPOqK8Qfwt4DYAw
Content-Length: 262
Date: Tue, 08 Jul 2014 19:23:42 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=PkW8U8SsPOqK8Qfwt4DYAw">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

But still i want to ask or understand (what i studied from the available resources) that who ever is opening a SSL socket need to have a SSL certificate, where we are doing that part of sending our SSL certificate to the server or that is being done by openssl library. Also i want to confirm that openssl provide SSL certificate that openssl is using and sending to server?

[This link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) help a bit to understand the basics of SSL security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you just use the [Paho Python client](http://eclipse.org/paho) library to deal with both the MQTT and SSL side of your problem?

A trivial example of subscribing to a topic on the test.mosquitto.org test server and printing the messages received, with SSL support:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho

def on_message(clnt, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

mqttc = paho.Client()
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.tls_set("mosquitto.org.crt") # http://test.mosquitto.org/ssl/mosquitto.org.crt
mqttc.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 8883)
mqttc.subscribe("bbc/#")
mqttc.loop_forever()
```